# Problem with mass INSERTs

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a set of objects (stored in a linkedlist) that need to be inserted into a SQL Server 2005 table.

This solution here is deadly slow.  I have about 10K records to insert. Every once in a while I pause and only see a few more execution done.

Can anyone help to improve this?

```
using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    dbConnection.Open();
    SqlTransaction dbTrans = dbConnection.BeginTransaction();       
    SqlCommand cmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand();  
    cmd.Transaction = dbTrans;    
    foreach (MyRecord myr in Records)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = buildInsertionString(MyRecord)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }                   
    dbTrans.Commit();
    dbConnection.Close();
}

public string buildinsertionString(Myrecod myr){
    string sqlCommandString = "insert into Table1 values";

    string values = "'" + myr.field1 + "',"
                            + myr.field2 + ","
                            + "'" + myr.field3 + "',"
                            + "'" + myr.field4 + "',"
                            + "'" + myr.field5 + "',"
                            + "'" + myr.field6 + "'";
    return sqlCommandString + "(" + values + ");

}
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: @gbn 2005 version, build 4035

Comment: Have you tried SqlBulkCopy? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: +1 for sqlbulkcopy comment ShortRound. Given the bulk logged or simple recovery model, this will resolve your issue. The bottleneck is the process of writing to the log RBAR. A minimally logged insert is the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`SQLBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) (`System.Data.SqlClient`):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table";

        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(Records);
    }
}
```

The SQL generated uses the [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command and functionality present in SQL Server 2005 and newer.

<sup>Note: `Records` must be of type `DataRow`, `DataTable`, or use `IDataReader`.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The only improvement you can make to your code is to parametrize the insert statement built by the buildInsertionString method so that the insert statement can be compiled once and reused by all subsequent calls for every record in the linked list. For example:

```
String insert = "insert into table (field) values (@value)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value",element);
```

Comment: +1 that would improve performance, too - since there's only one single query statement to parse and compile, and then it just gets called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to make use of passing a user defined table type into a stored procedure.  This is better than BulkInsert if you need the transactions logged for replication and if you have identity columns or are not supplying all the columns in the table.  Using your above code as an example, it would look like this:

On Sql Server:

```
Create Type dbo.MyRecord As Table
(
   field1 Varchar(50), -- Or whatever your types and names are
   field2 Varchar(50),
   field3 Varchar(50),
   field4 Varchar(50),
   field5 Varchar(50),
   field6 Varchar(50)
)
Go
Create Procedure dbo.spInsertTable1
(
   @vals dbo.MyRecord ReadOnly
)
As
Begin
   Insert Into dbo.Table1(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6)
   Select field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6
   From @vals
End
Go
```

On c# side:

```
using System.Linq;
....

using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   dbConnection.Open();
   SqlTransaction dbTrans = dbConnection.BeginTransaction();       
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spInsertTable1", dbConnection))
   {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Transaction = dbTrans;  
      var records = Records.Select(it =>
          new {
             field1 = it.field1,
             field2 = it.field2,
             field3 = it.field3,
             field4 = it.field4,
             field5 = it.field5,
             field6 = it.field6
          }).ToDataTable();
      var param  = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vals", records);
      param.TypeName = "dbo.MyRecord";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }

   dbTrans.Commit();
}

public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

    if (props == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Table properties.");
    if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
       PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
      table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    }
    object[] values = new object[props.Count];
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
      {
          values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
      }

      table.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can build up the SQL Statements into a single string separate by the GO command and send them over in one shot.  This should be a lot quicker.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


foreach(Thing thing in Something)
{
    string query = BuildMyQuery(thing);
    sb.Append(query);
    sb.Append("GO");
}

string SQLText = sb.ToString();

// Execute SQL Command here using SQL Text
```

Comment: Yeah really.  People are getting down vote happy around here.  It almost makes me not want to contribute anymore.....

Comment: Well, a downvote is one thing, but a downvote without a reason is another. It'd be nice to know what (if anything) is wrong with your answer. I don't see what's wrong myself.

Comment: Maybe Something should have been SomeOtherThing or Things.  :)

Comment: `GO` is not understood by the SQL Server Engine itself. It is just used as a batch delimiter in the client tools such as SSMS. semi colons could be used instead to delimit the individual statements but still SQLBulkCopy or one of the [various methods](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) of passing lists in and doing set processing would be better IMO.

Comment: I down voted because you completely missed the two enormous elephants in the question: 1) **never** set values to parameters via string concatenation and 2) not mentioning `BULK INSERT`s which exist exactly for this purpose... :-)

Comment: I disagree with option 1.  You can do this as long as you are not accepting the input from the client.  If the values are generated in code then you are not opening yourself up for sql injection.   For this instance bulk insert works - but what if your batch statements were not all inserts - but maybe you had a multitude of operations to perform against more than one table - this would be a better approach.  It also works well for multiple delete statements.

Comment: And for the record in a production application I normally use mappers (similar to ORM Products) to handle operations such as this so all of the commands are built up correct and parameter values are inspected for sql injection attacks.  Keep in mind I am used to coding against multiple database engines versus a single platform so it is difficult at times to take advantage of Vendor specific features.